# Problem getting authenticated user with Laravel Lumen + Passport

Tags: laravel, oauth-2.0, lumen, laravel-passport

I am using LumenPassport (https://github.com/dusterio/lumen-passport) and I followed a few tutorials listed here.

I used a combination of these tutorials as well as a heck of google and stackoverflow searches to achieve what I have thus far: 
http://esbenp.github.io/2017/03/19/modern-rest-api-laravel-part-4/
http://esbenp.github.io/2015/05/26/lumen-web-api-oauth-2-authentication/
https://blog.pusher.com/make-an-oauth2-server-using-laravel-passport/

What I achieved so far
1. Using password grant to get an access & refresh token
2. Storing these tokens in a secure http only cookie
3. Retrieving these tokens in Lumen's AuthServiceProvider

What I am unable to do
1. Getting the authenticated user with the AccessToken

I am trying to access either of these endpoints:

```
$router->group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function () use ($router) {
    $router->get('/', function () use ($router) {return $router->app->version();});
    $router->post('/logout', '\App\Auth\LoginController@logout');
});
```

I will immediately get an unauthorized error..  After some deep diving, the error comes from Authenticate.php which I know is called after AuthServiceProvider. I took a look at AuthServiceProvider and according to Lumen's documentation, this is how the boot method should looks like. Of course it is using the "api" driver and I had to switch it to "passport" for it to work.

**AuthServiceProvider.php**

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->app['auth']->viaRequest('passport', function ($request) {
         // dd("test") // this works
         // dd(Auth::user());
         // dd($request->user());
         // dd(Auth::guard('api')->user());
    });
}
```

**Authenticate.php**

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    if ($this->auth->guard($guard)->guest()) {
        $status = Response::HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED;
        return response()->json(['success' => false, 'status' => $status, 'message' => 'HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED'], $status);
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

From here, I am still unable to get any of the authenticated user's information. I have made sure to access these endpoints with Postman with the appropriate Authorization headers.

The reason why I need to retrieve the user is because I hope that in my logout method, I will be able to then retrieve the accessToken of that authenticated user and revoke the token and clear the cookies.

**LoginController.php**

```
public function logout()
    {
        // Get the accessToken from Auth
        // Need to fix AuthServiceProvider first
        $accessToken = $this->auth->user()->token();
        $refreshToken = $this->db
            ->table('oauth_refresh_tokens')
            ->where('access_token_id', $accessToken->id)
            ->update([
                'revoked' => true,
            ]);

        $accessToken->revoke();

        $this->cookie->queue($this->cookie->forget(self::REFRESH_TOKEN));
    }
```

Comment: I see you miss a return in your `AuthServiceProvider`, I suppose you have tried that? It should return null or User

Comment: @SvenHakvoort Hi Sven, sorry I had no idea why but my comment was somehow deleted. Anyway, I have already attempted that. In the Lumen documentation, it states the following code `$this->app['auth']->viaRequest('api', function ($request) {
    // Return User or null...
});` I understand that we have to return a user here but my problem is that I am unable to retrieve the user from the bearer access token that I sent in the headers. I have tried the different methods i.e. the 3 lines below dd('test') and they all responded with a socket hangup error.

Comment: Do you have `$app->configure('auth');` in your boostrap/app.php?

Comment: @SvenHakvoort Yes I do! I can verify that Auth works properly in LoginController.php@logout if I manually return a User in AuthServiceProvider.php@boot ... However, even if i do that, i am unable to get the token by calling `$this->auth->user()->token();` This led me to suspect that a token object is not created and linked to the user when it was created.

Comment: But that is another problem altogether, I wish to solve the part about getting the user first and figure the other problem later.

Answer (score 0):

At that point you cannot use `Auth::user()` since that function is the functionality for resolving that. So what you need to do is extract the bearer token with `$request->bearerToken()` and use that to retrieve your user.

**Update**
I took a look at your code and I would recommend the following:

An API is recommended to be 'stateless' meaning that it should not persist any state (i.e. cookies). It is far better to pass the access token with each request and let the application that accesses your API handle the tokens. Therefore I would recommend to remove the log-out functionality. Then you can do the following in your `AuthServiceProvider`:

```
 if ($token_exists) {
     $user = User::find($token->user_id);

     return $user;
 }
```

Comment: That will help me get the authorization access token, but how do I get the user associated with that access token?

Comment: That depends on how you get your token, can you provide more info about that?

Comment: I simply get the access token by calling /oauth/token with a post request `$client = new Client();
        $response = $client->post(sprintf('%s/oauth/token', $this->config->get('app.url')), $formParams);
        return json_decode((string) $response->getBody(), true);`

Comment: This is the route in my web.php `$router->post('/oauth/token', '\Dusterio\LumenPassport\Http\Controllers\AccessTokenController@issueToken');
`

Comment: Update: I tried to decode the access token in AuthServiceProvider and I was able to get the user_id. From there, I retrieved the user with eloquent and returned the user to the logout@LoginController.php. However, I realise that although I am able to get the user by calling $this->auth->user() in the logout method, I am unable to get the token still. I did a dd($this->auth->user()) and the accessToken field is still empty. It seems like it is not associated with the accessToken for some reason. I do have the HasApiTokens trait in my User model.

Comment: And your user model has 'use HasApiTokens'?

Comment: Yes Sven, it does have the 'use HasApiTokens'... My debugging session finds that it is not running the function inside the registerGuard@PassportServiceProvider.. I'm not sure if this could be the problem.

Comment: At the moment i dont have any other suggestions, however if you could provide me a repo with the code that you have right now i can take a look at it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189300/discussion-between-derrick-lee-and-sven-hakvoort).